# How to call operation contract from URL with MSMQ Binding in wcf

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, msmq, wcf-binding

I have a WCF service with MSMQ bindings and It's working fine. Whenever any message comes into the MSMQ Queue at that time. It is processing queues and message are removed from the queue. But its not calling operation contract and I am not getting information about message.

Is there any way to have your operation contract called directly or is there another way?. I am hosting wcf services in WAS and MSMQ and following is my web.config settings.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
          <binding name="WCFQNonTransactional" exactlyOnce="false">
              <security mode="None"/>
          </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyWCFService.MSMQReceiverServiceBehavior" name="MyWCFService.MSMQReceiverService">
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:90/MSMQReceiverService.svc"
                    binding="wsHttpBinding"
                    contract="MyWCFService.IMSMQReceiverService" name="mymsmq">
              <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost" />
              </identity>
          </endpoint>

          <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/Mywcfservice/msmqreceiverservice.svc"
                    binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="WCFQNonTransactional"
                    contract="MyWCFService.IMSMQReceiverService" />
      </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MyWCFService.MSMQReceiverServiceBehavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Comment: Queue permissions, deserialization errors. transactional queues?  Windows 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

If the operation contract is not being called this means there is a problem taking the message off the queue. Your operation code should be called for each message taken off the queue.

Firstly, make sure you are using transactional queues, because if you're not any errors will cause the message to be lost.

Secondly enable journalling on the client and server bindings and you will be able to trace the messages through.

Comment: could be lots of reasons. Queue permissions, deserialization errors.

Comment: If you're not using transactional queues then if there is a failure in the handling method the message will just disappear into a black hole without trace.

Comment: OK so should I use transactional queues then it will call my contract method? Do you think that code I have written in above web.config file is correct? I have having a GetMessage method. How it will call that method?

Comment: If you use transactional queues it still will not work. However you will more easily be able to tell if the message is even being passed to your message handler method. If the message remains on the queue this means that there is an exception being thrown either in your code or somewhere in the WCF service stack. You need to isolate this exception somehow.

Comment: OK How I can get that exception? its there any simple debugging techniques instead of using fiddler.

Comment: Enable end-to-end msmq event logging. This will give us a much clearer idea of whats going on: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730882.aspx